# iputils ping: -N (IPv6 node info query): purpose, usage, examples

Tags: ipv6, ping

What is the purpose of IPv6 node info query and how is used in [`ping`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/iputils-ping/ping.8.en.html)`-N ...`?